# UITableView troubles in 3.5inch and 4inch screens

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I have a UITableView which is 150 pixels wide. 
On the 4inch iPhone screen it shows all of the rows fine. 
On the 3.5inch iPhone screen it only shows half of the last row. How can I make sure it shows the full width of the last row.

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I added constraints to the UITableView and now it works perfectly on the iPhone 3.5 and the 4inch screens.